# Efficient solving of a linear system $A\,B\,x=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I was wondering, If there is an efficient method to solve a system of linear equations of the form

$$A\,B\,x=b$$
with $A=n\times m$ and $B=m\times n$ rectangular matrices and $x = n\times 1$ and $b=n\times 1$ vectors. The elements of $A$, $B$, $x$ and $b$ are complex and $n\approx 30-300$ and $m\approx 100-1000$.

So far I just multiply $A$ and $B$ and then use LU factorization with partial pivoting (the Maltab -operator). The system is quite ill-conditioned with cond$(A\,B)\approx 10^{20}$ or even worse.

Any ideas?

Comment: This condition number is awful ! If $A$ is (more or less) easily invertible (e.g., diagonal, tridiagonal, triangular...) you can solve instead $Bx=y$ with $y:=A^{-1}x$

Comment: @Azzo, mind elaborating how LP is usable here?

Comment: Michael: would SVD be too slow for your application?

Comment: Even though the condition number is that bad, the results are quite ok, since the picard conditions are fulfilled. I used SVD on $(A\,B)$ , which worked as good as LU and was still fast enough. I am only wondering if I can use the fact, that I have a matrix multiplication on the left hand side.

Comment: I also know that $(A\,B)$ becomes a symmetric or Hermitian matrix if that helps...

Comment: @Michael_K perfect then you can diagonalize AB.